# How to ensure referential integrity in Spark structured streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, referential-integrity

Till now we have a batch processing application, where we asked the source to inform us when to start our application based on their input signal called "trigger". So once we receive it, our application start consuming the data till that point by considering as a single batch.

But now we want to handle this in our application without dependent on Source input trigger message. In the new Spark streaming application, we want to consume and process the same Kafka topics.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: How we can be independent of trigger signal?

Comment: What determines when the trigger is fired, is it an end-of-day process or something?

Comment: Reading of Kafka events isn't "triggered"... You have a continuous stream of events, and Spark essentially has an "infinite while loop" polling this data... If you really want a "trigger", then you actually still need a batch application

Comment: I'm not sure that's what's being implied - @jeevankishore could you clarify here?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for an alternative to the trigger (indicator) from the source where they are checking the status of a rest job & publishing this, the best way to replace this to kick start my streaming job to consume the data published.